# OpenXML Excel Template

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, forms, winforms

I didn't understand how I can populate a new Excel file by copying it from a template.

This is the template:
[image]

Once I have copied the template into a new Excel file, when I write the data I lose the formatting of the columns and the colors of the sheet. Where have I gone wrong?

```
Public Sub ExportDTfromModel(ByVal pathmodel As String, ByVal pathdestination As String, ByVal dt As System.Data.DataTable)
    u.SegnalaSoloLog("Inizio Metodo: " & MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name.ToString())
    Try
        If System.IO.File.Exists(pathmodel) Then
            System.IO.File.Copy(pathmodel, pathdestination)

            Using spreadSheet As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(pathdestination, True)
                Dim WorksheetPart As WorksheetPart = GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadSheet, dt.TableName)
                If (Not WorksheetPart Is Nothing) Then
                    Dim worksheet As Worksheet = New Worksheet()
                    WorksheetPart.Worksheet = worksheet
                    Dim sheetData As SheetData = New SheetData()

                    Dim headerRow As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row()
                    Dim columns As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

                    For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                        columns.Add(column.ColumnName)
                        Dim cell As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell()
                        cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String
                        cell.CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(column.ColumnName)
                        '    Dim headerCell As Cell = createTextCell(
                        'ds.Columns.IndexOf(column) + 1,
                        '1,
                        'column.ColumnName)

                        headerRow.AppendChild(cell)
                    Next

                    sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow)

                    'For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Rows.Count - 1
                    '    Dim contentRow As DataRow
                    '    contentRow = ds.Rows(i)
                    '    sheetData.AppendChild(createContentRow(contentRow, i + 2))
                    'Next

                    For Each dsrow As DataRow In dt.Rows
                        Dim newRow As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row()

                        For Each col As String In columns
                            Dim cell As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell()
                            ' cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String


                            Select Case dsrow(col).GetType().ToString
                                Case "System.DateTime"
                                    cell.CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(Convert.ToDateTime(dsrow(col)))
                                    cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Date
                                Case "System.Decimal"
                                    cell.CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(Convert.ToDecimal(dsrow(col)))
                                    cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Number
                                Case "System.String"
                                    cell.CellValue = New DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow(col).ToString)
                                    cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String

                            End Select

                            newRow.AppendChild(cell)
                        Next

                        sheetData.AppendChild(newRow)
                    Next
                End If
                spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save()

                GC.Collect()
                u.SegnalaSoloLog("File Excel Generato in : " & pathdestination)

            End Using

        Else
            u.SegnalaSoloLog("Errore Modello non trovato, impossibile esportare il file")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        u.SegnalaSoloLog("Errore in Export from model: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Working with SpreadsheetML tables (Open XML SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-tables). You may consider downloading and installing the [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5) (OpenXMLSDKToolV25.msi) described [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK).

Comment: The following may be helpful as well: [Structure of a SpreadsheetML document (Open XML SDK)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/structure-of-a-spreadsheetml-document).

Comment: An important thing to know is that when a cell contains text (string data), the cell's actual value is saved to the [SharedString Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.sharedstringtable?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=openxml-2.8.1). The value within the cell contains the index of the value within the SharedString table. I believe that the indices are zero-based.  Example: If a cell contains the value `6`, you'll retrieve SharedStringItem with an index of `6` from the SharedStringTable.